# What is command of doubled \measuredangle?

Tags: symbols

What is command of `\measuredangle`  doubled?

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: There is no such predefined symbol available, I'm afraid.

Comment: If there is some standard usage for this symbol can you please provide a reference -- just curious.

Comment: echoing @PeterGrill's comment, if there *is* a standard usage and a reference (in a published source), i will be happy to submit it to unicode.

Comment: @ Peter Grill  , @  barbara beeton
yes it is exists in a geometry book that i am typing now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no predefined symbol, as far as I know; you can get a decent emulation with `picture` mode. It's not really good at scriptscript size, but I don't think you'll need it at such level.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\measuredangledouble}{%
  \mathord{\mathpalette\@measangdbl\relax}%
}

\newcommand{\@measangdbl}[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\measuredangle$}%
  \setlength\unitlength{\wd\z@}%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle
    \def\@mangle{50}\def\@mratio{0.96}%
  \fi
  \ifx#1\textstyle
    \def\@mangle{50}\def\@mratio{0.96}%
  \fi
  \ifx#1\scriptstyle
    \def\@mangle{42}\def\@mratio{0.83}%
  \fi
  \ifx#1\scriptscriptstyle
    \def\@mangle{36}\def\@mratio{0.67}%
  \fi
  \begin{picture}(1,\@mratio)
  \roundcap\roundjoin\linethickness{0.06\unitlength}
  \polyline(0.9,\@mratio)(0.1,0.03)(0.9,0.03)
  \put(0.1,0.03){\arc[-3,\@mangle]{0.4}}
  \put(0.1,0.03){\arc[-3,\@mangle]{0.55}}
  \end{picture}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\measuredangle\measuredangledouble$

$\scriptstyle\measuredangle\measuredangledouble$

$\scriptscriptstyle\measuredangle\measuredangledouble$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Deleted since apparently not useful ...

Here's a Ti*k*Z version, not perfect so far.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newsavebox{\tempboxa}
\newcommand{\doubledmeasuredangle}[1][.]{%  Note: '.' is a placeholder for the current color. 
  \savebox{\tempboxa}{$\measuredangle$}%
  \resizebox{\wd\tempboxa}{\ht\tempboxa}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1.5,#1]
      \draw (1,0) coordinate (A) -- (0,0) coordinate (B)
      -- (1,1) coordinate (C)
      pic [draw,line width=1.5,angle radius=0.5cm] {angle = A--B--C}
  pic [draw,line width=1.5,angle radius=0.25cm] {angle = A--B--C};
      \draw (B) -- (1.2,0);
      \draw (B) -- (0.84585,0.84585);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}


\begin{document}

$\measuredangle$ \doubledmeasuredangle

{\large

$\measuredangle$ \doubledmeasuredangle
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Improved version**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\def\measuredangleangle{45}

\newsavebox{\tempboxa}
\newcommand{\doubledmeasuredangle}[1][.]{%
  \savebox{\tempboxa}{$\measuredangle$}%
  \resizebox{\wd\tempboxa}{\ht\tempboxa}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1.75,line join=round,line cap=round,#1]
      \pgfmathcos{\measuredangleangle};
      \edef\temppgfmathone{\pgfmathresult}
      \pgfmathsin{\measuredangleangle};
      \edef\temppgfmathtwo{\pgfmathresult}
      \typeout{\temppgfmathtwo\space \temppgfmathone}
      \draw (1,0.0) coordinate (A) -- (0,0) coordinate (B)
      -- (\temppgfmathone,\temppgfmathtwo) coordinate (C)
      pic [draw,line width=1.75,angle radius=0.5cm] {angle = A--B--C}
      pic [draw,line width=1.75,angle radius=0.25cm] {angle = A--B--C};
      \pgfmathparse{tan(\measuredangleangle)};
      \edef\temppgfmathtwo{\pgfmathresult}
      \coordinate (FinalB) at (1.0,\pgfmathresult);
      \draw (B) -- (FinalB);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}




\begin{document}
\textcolor{blue}{$\measuredangle$ \doubledmeasuredangle}

{\large
  $\measuredangle$ \doubledmeasuredangle
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it looks better with the two arcs closer, as in egreg's answer

Comment: @User: That's a personal opinion. I leave that to the O.P.

Comment: Besides moving the two arcs closer, I'd recommend `line width=1.75, line cap=round, join=round` to get it closer to the other symbol.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I am working already on a better version, thanks -- and I have found the `round` values too.